# Ошибка при скачивании pyaudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Ошибка при скачивании `pyaudio`:

```
pip install pyaudio
```

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\clcla\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\clcla\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l7hgrezp\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\clcla\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l7hgrezp\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\clcla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-05j14jsb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\clcla\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\clcla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l7hgrezp\pyaudio\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\clcla\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\clcla\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\clcla\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: MS_WIN64: Ё§¬Ґ­Ґ­ЁҐ ¬ Єа®®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­Ёп
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: б¬. ЇаҐ¤л¤гйҐҐ ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "MS_WIN64"
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\clcla\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\clcla\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l7hgrezp\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\clcla\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l7hgrezp\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\clcla\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-05j14jsb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\clcla\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы в системе стоял компилятор от Visual Studio, т.к. та библиотека это не чисто на питоне, а с с/с++, поэтому ее в процессе установки нужно скомпилировать. Другой вариант скачать и установить готовые скомпилированные сборки: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Answer (score 0):

В pip регистр имеет очень важное значение в названии библиотеки. Чисто гипотетически, pyaudio и PyAudio могут быть совершенно разными библиотеками, но это  так, к слову. Скорее всего, проблему решит просто написание команды так: `pip install PyAudio`, вместо вашего `pip install pyaudio`. PS: что в дальнейшем правильно писать названия библиотек, смотрите команду для скачивания в PyPi.